# Why is OpenMP speed slower than serial

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, output, openmp

I was running both my serial and OpenMP program when I noticed that the OpenMP program is much slower than the serial program when it comes to testing a certain amount of threads. Why is that? Does it have to do with the code itself for the OpenMP program? or does it have to do with pc performance? Appreciate the assistance.

Serial Code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static long num_steps = 1024*1024*1024;
#define MIN_BLK  1024*1024*124

double pi_comp(int Nstart,int Nfinish,double step)
{  int i,iblk;
double x, sum = 0.0,sum1, sum2;
if (Nfinish-Nstart < MIN_BLK){
  for (i=Nstart;i< Nfinish; i++){
     x = (i+0.5)*step;
     sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
  }
}
else{
  iblk = Nfinish-Nstart;
  sum1 = pi_comp(Nstart,         Nfinish-iblk/2,step);
  sum2 = pi_comp(Nfinish-iblk/2, Nfinish,       step);
  sum = sum1 + sum2;
}return sum;
}
int main ()
{
int i;
double step, pi, sum;
double init_time, final_time;
step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

init_time = omp_get_wtime();
sum = pi_comp(0,num_steps,step);
pi = step * sum;
final_time = omp_get_wtime() - init_time;
printf(" for %ld steps pi = %f in %f secs\n",num_steps,pi,final_time);

}
```

OpenMP code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static long num_steps = 1024*1024*1024;
#define MIN_BLK  1024*1024*124

double pi_comp(int Nstart,int Nfinish,double step)
{  
int i,iblk;
double x, sum = 0.0,sum1, sum2;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (i=Nstart;i< Nfinish; i++){
    x = (i+0.5)*step;
    sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
}
return sum;
}
int main ()
{
int i;
double step, pi, sum;
double init_time, final_time;
step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

init_time = omp_get_wtime();
sum = pi_comp(0,num_steps,step);
pi = step * sum;
final_time = omp_get_wtime() - init_time;
printf(" for %ld steps pi = %f in %f secs\n",num_steps,pi,final_time);

}
```

Output:

```
./pi_recur 
for 1073741824 steps pi = 3.141593 in 4.620267 secs
./pi_recur_omp 
for 1073741824 steps pi = 3.146991 in 6.572116 secs
```

Comment: Why care about execution time when the estimate of `pi` from the OpenMP code is so far from the true value?  Pay a little attention to the comment on the answer below.

Comment: Note that your serial and parallel codes are different.

Answer (score 2):

Using OpenMP does not make everything faster.
You need to think about how memory is use and how it can be shared on a parallel way.
In your particular case, you have to declare "double x" inside the for loop because not doing so end up with a "race condition resulting in an undefined behavior" as pointed out by Jérôme Richard on the comment below, where he also suggest "An alternative solution is to use the clause `private(x)`"

In my PC running your code:
serial code gives me a time of 2.25136 secs.
omp code gives me a time of 5.24389 secs.

Changing where x is declared:
Defining x inside the for loop in with omp gives me: 0.607630 sec.

Happy coding!

Comment: Note that making `x` local to the loop is not just good for performance. It is mainly good for *correctness*. The initial OpenMP code has a *race condition* resulting in an undefined behaviour. This race condition is the root of the performance issue: it causes threads to compete for the same cache line (that cannot be modified in parallel). An alternative solution is to use the clause `private(x)`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have edit my answer to incorporate your comment.